# Bot setup for Skype for Business hybrid environment

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business, azure-bot-service

In Bot setup for Skype for Business hybrid environment, can the on-prem step (New-CsHybridApplicationEndpoint) be ignored as we would like only our online users to use the bot.

Answer (score 0):

The Skype for Business bot setup instructions are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/bot-hybrid-support

I'm not aware of an 'on-prem only' solution, just hybrid or online.  Nonetheless, using the hybrid configuration, only users in your tenant will be able to communicate with the bot.

> Skype for Business bots can only communicate to users in the same
>   domain/tenant

Comment: It's not an 'on-prem only' solution. We are trying to achieve an 'Online Only' in a hybrid environment. So in the hybrid environment, there are two steps
1. CsOnlineApplication
2. CsHybridApplication

The question is after CsOnlineApplication can we disregard the CsHybridApplication?